# ImageSharp drawing shapes on image in Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, imagesharp

I am using `ImageSharp` (ver 1.0.0-beta0006) in my .Net Core 2.2 project. I primarily use it to resize image (to generate thumbnail) and it's working fine.

Recently, I've got a requirement to draw rectangles on the image. Based on [the documentation](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/blob/master/tests/ImageSharp.Benchmarks/Drawing/DrawLines.cs), this is what I've got to do:

```
using (var image = new Image<Rgba32>(800, 800))
        {
            image.Mutate(x => x.DrawLines(
                Rgba32.HotPink,
                10,
                new SixLabors.Primitives.PointF[] {
                    new Vector2(10, 10),
                    new Vector2(550, 50),
                    new Vector2(200, 400)
                }));

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.SaveAsBmp(stream);
            }
        }
```

However, I realize that in my `Mutate` lambda methods there is not a method named `DrawLines`. Can I know if I'm missing an assembly? Based on the documentation, it is `using`:

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
```

both of which are found in the `SixLabors.ImageSharp` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing` and you should be able to find the missing methods/extensions.

Image sharp is split into 2 main libraries, the main `SixLabors.ImageSharp` which deals with the core image decoding/encoding and pixel pushing, then there is `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing` which handles various drawing sub systems, vector drawing, text rendering etc.